# Get an Optional, Generic, value from an Object

Tags: typescript, option-type, fp-ts

Say I have the following four objects:

```
const foo1: Readonly<{foo: number, bar: ?string}> = {
   foo: 123
}

const foo1: Readonly<{foo: number, bar: ?string}> = {
   foo: 123,
   bar: '1123'
}


const bar1: Readonly<{foo2: number, bar2: ?string}> = {
   foo2: 123
}

const foo1: Readonly<{foo: number, bar: ?string}> = {
   foo2: 123,
   bar2: '1123'
}
```

I now want to convert them into fp-ts `Option` bearing objects of the form:

```
{foo: number, bar: Option<string>}
```

The naive approach is to write two functions (or to indeed do those computations inline):

```
const makeOptional1 = (obj: Readonly<{foo: number, bar: ?string}>) => {
  return (obj.bar === undefined) ? none : some(obj[key]
}

const makeOptional2 = (obj: Readonly<{foo2: number, bar2: ?string}>) => {
  return (obj.bar2 === undefined) ? none : some(obj[key]
}
```

But say, that I wanted to extract a more abstracted function, one which could take an arbitrary object and arbitrary key, and return the correct Option.

A first attempt might look something like so:

```
const optionalKey = <T, D>(val: D, key: string): Option<T> => {
  if (val[key] === undefined) {
    return none
  } else {
    return some(val[key])
  }
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)
```

The error message makes perfect sense but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas would be welcome

Comment: What version of fp-ts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please take a look:
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhMNgQHYBo4cwUxwGcIR84BfOAMylLgHJqwBaGIhgbgCheBjTEXjUIEAIwAuOACV8AQwAmmADYBPADxIREKRgCuIAEb4oOQ3KgB%20KUKjAMAc0oA%20OAF5E3ON5qipYgCYAZm4KfkFhUQCpWUUVDS0-XANjUzhzKxsYO0cXd08fXx04QKCsLx8MqQYxUoZQ3m4BDCF0i0kZeSUMNU0i6OSjEzMLAOs4W3snClcPBArvbQHShqaItqgB2O7exIgB-SG0jLGsnOnZgp8l-2DywpPq2uD6sLWW%20BA5AGt8AHlUOgMHJlGJ8uoACpwfAADxg%20AwCiInTiPQSRV0KWGG3Gk1yMxwAGloXCEUi4L9VBBqHAIc4ABQQQwAKykEJwlKkhIAlO5XPNClB8DA9FAMHBGSyAHQZdxuDx6RH4aj2fAKXmWXAEOA2Uj4SXMgDalIAutzVs1Wl9fgC0JgQQFwVDYfDEcjtvE%20jdBqkRptcdkpi4iSTXeTKdTaQymazaRz8Kouby3PyFnAhSKxRKYzLRnKFUqVRg1RqtcWdRM9QbjQmzRb1ig7cDlISE06Qy6yciIzS6fSAG4gtnxxNwHl8q7eYA0gcgmuqE35uCKhTK1XqyeFdPC0XivDFtNUfDKIjkAVb7wZ3eVsiz5TzuuFMIUIA)

```js
import { Option, some, none } from 'fp-ts/lib/Option';


const foo1: Readonly<{ foo: number, bar?: string }> = {
  foo: 123
}

const foo2: Readonly<{ foo: number, bar?: string }> = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: '1123'
}


const bar1: Readonly<{ foo2: number, bar2?: string }> = {
  foo2: 123
}

const bar2: Readonly<{ foo2: number, bar2?: string }> = {
  foo2: 123,
  bar2: '1123'
}

const makeOptional1 = <T extends Readonly<{ foo: number, bar?: string }>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => {
  return (obj.bar === undefined) ? none : some(obj[key])
}

const makeOptional2 = <T extends Readonly<{ foo2: number, bar2?: string }>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => {
  return (obj.bar2 === undefined) ? none : some(obj[key])
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];



const optionalKey = <T, K extends keyof T>(val: T, key: K): Option<Values<T>> => val[key] ? some(val[key]) : none;

const result = optionalKey({ age: 1 }, 'age'); // Option<number>
```

fp-ts version:2.8.6